# store multiple values in one cell of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I would like to store multiple values in one cell of an array using Python.
I have a system described at Nx positions and Nt times. I need to know 3 numerical values A, B and C at each of these positions and times. The end goal is to put all these into a dataframe. My idea is not usable because np.arrray can't store more than one value at each location.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Nx=10
Nt=10
Data_1D_full=np.zeros((Nx-1,Nt))

for t in range (Nt):
    for i in range(0,Nx-1):
        A = 'A'
        B = 'B'
        C = 'C'
        Data_temp = np.array([A, B, C])
        Data_end[i,t]=Data_temp

df= pd.DataFrame(Data_end)
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I guess you can use standard-python and just simply use a tuple for each entry of said array. I guess then it would look like `[(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), ... (aN,bN,cN)]`

Comment: As each value A, B, C is dependant on the location (i,t), and I have a LOT of locations in the real application, your solution can't  be implemented, but I thank you for your contribution.

Comment: What are A, B and C supposed to represent? Are they actually supposed to represent string values?